# autohotkey: how to avoid "focus lost" problem

Tags: autohotkey

I have such autohotkey script:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
Run file.exe              # takes ~30 seconds to start
WinWait User identification
Sleep 1000
Send administrator{tab}
Sleep 1000
Send password
Click 38, 196
```

I'm using this script at start-up to auto-logon one utility.

The problem is - if when this script is working (for about 2 seconds + application start-up time (about 30 seconds) 32 seconds in total) some other program pop-up a window about something (like new update available or antivirus claim or anything) the script doesn't work because the focus of the window "User identification" is lost.

How to workaround this problem? Should I use another tool (which one) or it's possible to solve this problem using autohotkey?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used AutoScriptWriter program that generates code for me perfectly:

```
Run file.exe
WinWait, User identification,
IfWinNotActive, User identification, , WinActivate, User identification, 
WinWaitActive, User identification, 
Send, administrator{TAB}password{ENTER}
```

However `ControlSend` likely better choice

Comment: Glad you got it working. Just as a tip - have a look at the ControlSend and ControlClick commands as well. If something steals focus while your current script is entering data it will cause problems. Sending keystrokes/clicks directly to controls is more reliable and doesn't require the window to have focus.